# alternate background color for radios in radiobuttonlist?

Tags: asp.net, coding-style, controls

I am trying to alternate background colors for items in radiobuttonlist using the below code, similar code  is working on dropdownlist items

```
            If color Then
                        rdBtnList.Items.FindByText(lstItem.Text).Attributes.CssStyle.Add("style", "background: white;")
                        rdBtnList.Items.FindByText(lstItem.Text).Attributes.CssStyle.Add("style", "background-color: white;")
                    Else
                        rdBtnList.Items.FindByText(lstItem.Text).Attributes.CssStyle.Add("style", "background-color: LightSlateGray;")
                        rdBtnList.Items.FindByText(lstItem.Text).Attributes.CssStyle.Add("style", "background: LightSlateGray;")
                    End If

                    color = Not color
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

that worked

```
 rdBtnList.Items.FindByText(lstItem.Text).Attributes.Add("style", "color: black;font-weight:bold;")
```